# Not using mathcal, but still getting "Error: \mathcal allowed only in math mode"

Tags: math-mode, errors, mathcal

I am recieving a TeX error as follows:

```
! LaTeX Error: \mathcal allowed only in math mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.165 ... profits \emph{while prices remain fixed}
                                                  . So if we allow
```

But as you can see, line 165 does not have a `\mathcal`! Line 165 and surrounding tex reads as follows:

```
Using Calvo pricing, the objective is to maximise the expected present
value of real profits \emph{while prices remain fixed}. So if we allow
$\Lambda_{k,t}$ to be the stochastic discount factor between $t$
and $k$, we obtain:
```

Not a `\mathcal` in sight. I *am* using mathcal, but only in mathmode and using macros defined as follows:

```
\global\long\def\em{\mathcal{M}}%

\global\long\def\kay{\mathcal{K}}%

\global\long\def\arr{\mathcal{R}}%
```

These shortcuts are then used in certain equations. What am I doing wrong? I've never had this problem before.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Please provide the `MWE` is in executable format, i.e., from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: always use `\newcommand` if you use `\def` you can (as shown here) overwrite core latex features with no warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you redefine the `\em` macro... which is used I guess inside the `\emph{...}` macro (you can also emphasize a text via `{\em your text}`):

```
\global\long\def\em{\mathcal{M}}%
```

Maybe give another name, like:

```
\global\long\def\cM{\mathcal{M}}%
```

Also, next time please provide a full, compilable Minimal Working Example (MWE).

Comment: To be precise, the kernel has `\DeclareTextFontCommand{\emph}{\em}`.